# How to create this java comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I have this class:

```
public class Test {

  private int    priority;
  private String desciption;
...
}
```

and I have this arraylist:

```
Priority: 1, Description: C2
Priority: 2, Description: C1
Priority: 3, Description: C1
Priority: 4, Description: C2
```

I want this result:

```
Priority: 1, Description: C2
Priority: 4, Description: C2
Priority: 2, Description: C1
Priority: 3, Description: C1
```

How I have to do this with comparator?
Thank you!

EDIT:

I reply to all of your questions:

@retro: no. description is a string without a specific format. it can be empty, too.

@tobias_k: first "group" by description and than order by priority. priority is always not equals.

@user270349:

this is my try:

```
int result = 0;
if (o1.getPriority() < o2.getPriority()) result = -1;
else if (o1.getPriority() > o2.getPriority()) result = 1

result *= o1.getDescription().compareTo(o2.getDescription());

return result;
```

EDIT 2:

another input/output example:

and I have this arraylist:

```
Priority: 1, Description: C2
Priority: 2, Description: C3
Priority: 3, Description: C1
Priority: 4, Description: C2
```

I want this result:

```
Priority: 1, Description: C2
Priority: 4, Description: C2
Priority: 2, Description: C3
Priority: 3, Description: C1
```

THIS IS MY SOLUTION:

```
            List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<>();
    testList.add(new Test(4, "C2"));
    testList.add(new Test(2, "C3"));
    testList.add(new Test(3, "C1"));
    testList.add(new Test(1, "C2"));


    Comparator<Test> comparator = new Comparator<Test>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
            int res = o1.getDescription().compareTo(o2.getDescription());
            if (res == 0)
                return o1.getPriority() < o2.getPriority() ? -1 : 1;
            else
                return res;
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(testList, comparator);


    List<String> valoriInseriti = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Test> grouping = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Test t : testList) {
        if (!valoriInseriti.contains(t.getDescription())) {
            valoriInseriti.add(t.getDescription());
            grouping.add(t);
        }
    }


    comparator = new Comparator<Test>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
            return o1.getPriority() < o2.getPriority() ? -1 : 1;
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(grouping, comparator);


    Collections.sort(testList, comparator);

    List<Test> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Test t1 : grouping) {
        for (Test t2 : testList) {
            if (t2.getDescription().equals(t1.getDescription())) {
                output.add(t2);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("==============================");
    for (Test t : output)
        System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: Do the descriptions always have the same format? Always one char, one digit? Can there be other chars, more digits?

Comment: Please describe how you want the comparator to work: Primarily by description, descending, and secondarily by priority, ascending? Also, what have you tried, and what's the problem?

Comment: What did you try? What don't you understand about Comparator interface in the javadoc? What is the requirement (in English, not just an example). -1

Comment: I think your code is right but don't match the requirements. I think, IMHO, that you didn't understand the requirements. Maybe you need to group by description and sort the groups by the highest priority in the group and then sort within the group by priority too? I wouldn't do that just sorting with a comparator. I would represent as objects the groups themselves.

Comment: @user270349: I understand the problem and the question is if I can solve this problem with only comparator or not :)

Comment: I think you can not do this with a comparator or the comparable interface. If you want to group the items by description and then compare those groups, then you have to compare all elements at once, not just two, as Comparator and Comparable would do.

Comment: yeah! i update my question with my solution. if you have a compact, clean and perform solution, you're welcome. thank you all!

Answer (score 4):

`Test implements Comparator`  and override `compare()` method

```
  public class Test implements Comparator<Test>{
    private int    priority;
    private String desciption;

    @Override
    public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
       // your code here
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Comparator<Test> myComparator = new Comparator<Test>() {
    public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
        int result = o2.desciption.compareTo(o1.desciption);

        if (result == 0) {
            return o1.priority - o2.priority;
        }

        return result;

    }
};

List<Test> sortedList = Collections.sort(testList, myComparator);
```

Comment: this example work with example, but if i have this input

Priority: 1, Description: C2
Priority: 2, Description: C3
Priority: 3, Description: C1
Priority: 4, Description: C2

the output should be

Priority: 1, Description: C2
Priority: 4, Description: C2
Priority: 2, Description: C3

and your example doesn't work. thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

First thing you want to do is make your `Test` class implement `Comparator`.

```
public class Test implements Comparator<Test> {
    // Fields etc.

    public int compare(Test test1, Test test2)
    {
         // Add your logic in here.
         return test1.getDescription().compareTo(test2.getDescription()) * -1;
    }
}
```

This will work because `String` compares lexographically. It will attempt to sort in ascending order, in terms of the first letter. If the first letter is equal, it will move onto the next value. By reversing it, you can store in descending order.

Then you sort it, use `Collections.sort(myList);`. And here is a working ideone example: http://ideone.com/SdFGFg

Comment: Shouldn't it rather implement `Comparable`?

Comment: _Shouldn't it rather implement_  Only if this comparison is the logical way to compare then, quite/most often the required order of comparison is required it in a different component and there may well be different sorting requirements.

Comment: Agreed that `Comparable` should only be used for the one natural comparison (if any), and any "funny" comparisons should be done with `Comparator`. But then IMHO the `Comparator` should be a separate class, and not the class of the object to be compared.

Comment: I think, in terms of good design, the Comparator should be a completely different class rather than an anonymous object, but I do think that for the context of the question, this answer would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Comparator<Test> comparator = new Comparator<Test>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
                return o1.desciption.compareTo(o2.desciption);
            }
                  };
```

As, your problem specifies, you want to order the object of `Test` class in descending order with respect to `description` field, use `Collections.reverseOrder(comparator)`

```
Comparator<Test>reverse = Collections.reverseOrder(comparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

Your TestComparator

```
class TestComparator implements Comparator<Test> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {

        String[] arr1 = o1.getDesciption().split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
        String[] arr2 = o2.getDesciption().split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
        if(Integer.parseInt(arr2[1])!=Integer.parseInt(arr1[1])){
            return  new Integer(Integer.parseInt(arr2[1])).compareTo(Integer.parseInt(arr1[1]));
        }
        if(o1.getPriority()!=o2.getPriority()){
           return   new Integer(o1.getPriority()).compareTo(o2.getPriority());
        }
        return 0;
    }    
}
```

your sorting

```
 System.out.println(list);      
 Collections.sort(list,new TestComparator());
 System.out.println("After sorting");
 System.out.println(list);
```

your output

```
[Test [priority=1, desciption=C2], Test [priority=2, desciption=C1], Test [priority=3, desciption=C1], Test [priority=4, desciption=C2]]
After sorting
[Test [priority=1, desciption=C2], Test [priority=4, desciption=C2], Test [priority=2, desciption=C1], Test [priority=3, desciption=C1]]
```

Comment: this example work with example, but if i have this input Priority: 1, Description: C2 Priority: 2, Description: C3 Priority: 3, Description: C1 Priority: 4, Description: C2 the output should be Priority: 1, Description: C2 Priority: 4, Description: C2 Priority: 2, Description: C3 and your example doesn't work. thank you anyway!

Comment: @FabioMignogna Please update your question with your input and  expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should sort (with comparator), then group, then sort the groups (with another comparator that may use the first comparator applied to the first element on the list), then degroup.